# OCaml - issues connected with using fold__

Tags: ocaml

I have a several questions connected with fold_left/right.

1. How to accumulate two or more values? If using a tuple is good solution ?
2. How to abort work of fold ? For example we must find firstly occurrence of any number, and return position. I mean a break (C++).

Comment: `we must find firstly occurrence of any number` then you must traverse all your list [1;1;1;1;5], no need to abort here. To deal with partial recursion there are other function like dropwhile, takewhile ... Or you can define the one you need. See folding as projection between type, you have a source type and a target type with a seed value (the accumulator), then folding is a procedure which realize this transformation. Yes using tuple is good solution, IMO.

Answer (score 1):

zurgl's comment is a great answer (maybe move it down to the answer region).

You can use an exception to terminate a fold early. It's good to try to structure your code so you don't have to do this (in my opinion). Code without exceptions is easier to understand, more composable, parallelizable, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`we must find firstly occurrence of any number` then you must traverse all your list [1;1;1;1;5], no need to abort here. To deal with partial recursion there are other function like dropwhile, takewhile ... Or you can define the one you need. See folding as projection between type, you have a source type and a target type with a seed value (the accumulator), then folding is a procedure which realize this transformation. Yes using tuple is good solution, IMO.